# JQuery get the class within a parent

Tags: jquery, html, class, parent

I have literally spent hours with JQuery trying to extract a piece of text from a class, in the code below you can see that when the **reply** button is clicked JQuery looks for a class called **name** in order to extract a piece of text which in this instance is **bob green**.

I am always one to research these type of things but since none of this code works I am stuck, in the JQuery code below you can see that I have tried different ways in extracting the text.

If anyone could help me fix this problem I would be more than grateful.

```
<div class='replyContainer'>
    <div class='image'></div>
    <span>
        <div class='close' title='Close'></div>
        <b><font class='name'>bob green</font></b>
        test message
    </span>
    <div class='bubble-triangle-border'></div>
    <div class='bubble-triangle'></div>
    <div class='info'> 
        <div class='reply'></div>
    </div>
</div>


$(".replyContainer .reply").live('click',function(){    
    var replyName = "@" + $(this).parent().parent(".name").text();
});


$(".replyContainer .reply").live('click',function(){    
    var replyName = "@" + $(this).parent().parent().closest(".name").text();
});

$(".replyContainer .reply").live('click',function(){    
    var replyName = "@" + $(this).parent().parent("span font.name").text();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $(".replyContainer .reply").live("click", function() { 
      var replyName = "@" + $(this).closest(".replyContainer").find(".name").text()
 })
```

A few other things:

1. jQuery.live() is considered deprecated (see: http://api.jquery.com/live/), you should use `.delegate()` or .`on()` instead.
2. You should totally not use the `<font>` tag but use CSS!
3. `closest()` goes up the DOM parents and their parents, and `find()` goes downward and looks at children!

Comment: +1 for ultra speed, and deprecation and best practices note to boot ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".replyContainer .reply").live('click',function(){    
var replyName = "@" + $(this).closest('div.replyContainer').find('font.name').text();
});
```